# 2 distinct configurations for same mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm building a tool to parse an org-mode source file to generate an html5 presentation. This works more or less.

When editing the source file in emacs it would be really handy if I could define functions, keybindings , snippets and such for this independent of my existing org-mode configuration. (or any other major mode, this is not org-mode specific)

I looked into cloning org-mode and renaming it but that seems like  overkill to me

Ideally I'd like something like this

For standard org-mode

```lisp
(use-package org

:mode ("\\.org\\'" . org-mode)

...

:bind

("s-f12" . do-something)

)
```

and for my presentation mode

```lisp
(use-package org

:mode ("\\.orgp\\'" . org-mode)

...

bind:

("s-f12" . do-something-else)

)
```

When opening foo.orgp I would find org-mode with an alternative configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
(defvar my-orgp-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "s-f12") 'do-something-else)
    map))

(define-derived-mode my-orgp-mode org-mode "OrgP"
  "A variant of Org mode specifically for my HTML5 presentations.")
```

and then use `my-orgp-mode` for files matching `\\.orgp\\'`.

Comment: Wow you beat me to it by 11 minutes. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

OK as usual the answer is obvious once you post the question.
using

```lisp
(define-derived-mode org-presentation-mode org-mode "org-presentation mode"
  "a variant of org-mode"

  (defun runPresentationTool ()
    (interactive)
    (message "this should run the presentation tool")
    )

  )

(provide 'org-presentation-mode)
```

and

```lisp
use-package org-presentation-mode
```

Does the trick nicely

Comment: Don't use `defun` within `define-derived-mode` (nor within other `defun`s or `defmacro`s for that matter):  it will still have a global effect anyway, so better move the `defun` outside so it's "more honest".